# libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 Reinstall Error

Tags: 16.04

I'm getting this error message:

> E: The package libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 needs to be reinstalled, but
>   I can't find an archive for it.

I tried this to fix:

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0

but it always returns this:

> E: The package libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 needs to be reinstalled, but
>   I can't find an archive for it.

I'm running 16.04.

Thanks

Dave

Comment: Make sure you have [enabled the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: I had to update my sources to include the archive directories:

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe multiverse deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe multiverse

I then did: sudo apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 but I got a message that it was half-installed.

To fix that I did a sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq --dry-run libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0:amd64 but that reported it was in a very bad inconsistent state

To fix that I did a sudo apt-get install --reinstall libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0:amd64